# Export results of foreach loop to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

My script looks great on console, but I would like to write/export the results to a `.csv` file. I tried creating a variable, and then pipe the result to another `cmdlet`, but that doesn't seem to work because of the additional pipe before my loop starts.

```
Get-ADGroup -Server "company.com" -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=Users,OU=Corporate,..."
| Sort-Object Name 
| ForEach-Object{
    $_ | Select-Object Name,@{
      Name = 'User'
      Expression = {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ 
                   | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name}
    }
  }  
| Where-Object {$_.Name}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I adjusted the formatting concerning pipes. Further improvements are necessary, because the question still needs the correct tags to categorize it properly. Tagging it as 'CSV' is not sufficient. Some things are missing, but I cannot assess them.

Comment: I didn't know what else to choose as a tag so all I could think of was .csv. I want to output my results to a .csv file and was looking for the proper syntax to accomplish that. If there is a tag for that please let me know.

Comment: i discovered what I was doing wrong with trying to print to a .csv file. I changed the bottom of the script

Comment: ForEach-Object{

$_ | Select-Object Name,@{

Name = 'User'

Expression = {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name}

}
} | Out-file c:\temp\My_Test.csv

Comment: But my results are all in one column and I would like to have two separate columns of information and the one column cuts the names off with a "...." Do I need to create a table to get a all of my users names ? How would I do that ?  thanks for the help.